# Is there any way to clear search history in find/replace box in VS Code 1.70.1 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-code, find-replace

My case: I have a lot of search inputs. Often I need to clear this history, make two or little more search inputs and switch between them.
I have only found a way to solve my problem with Windows registry.
F1 - Search: Clear Search History also doesn't clear history in find/replace bar.
Maybe there is a command in VS Code that can do it without modifying registry?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a way to do that for the FInd widget history.  You may need to file an issue requesting it.

Comment: You may want to make  note to clarify that you aren't talking about the "Find in Files" UI, which _does_ get cleared by the command to clear search history.

Comment: I did a small experiment and searched three different words- let's say they are A, B, and C. If I search A, then B, then C, the history has A, B, C. Then If I search A, the history now has B, C, A. ie. the most recent search moves past instances to the most recent position in the history list. The only confusing part is that if you empty the search box, in order to go to the most recent entry, you need to press the down arrow key instead of up, which for some reason takes me to its second-most-recent search history entry. If this is a sufficient answer, let me know and I'll write it up.

Comment: @DavidFong, thanks for your respond! I also have tried to play with sequence of my search inputs, it works but there is another confusing part for me. Regularly I write regex inputs then I modify it  and they are quite long and often I don't see ending of my input in widget (I write it in notepad and then copy it to find box). So there are a lot of "same" request in visible area of find box and I don't really see what input is chosen. It's my problem...

Comment: You can resize the box horizontally (there is a resize sash on the left side of the box). You can also use the "End" key to go to the end of the line. I have some keyboard mappings to not have to move my hands around much to do that. Let me know if you're interested.